# How to toggle bootstrap DatePicker by setting readonly attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I tried to set `datepicker` to be enable or disable `datepicker` according first selection. If user select option "Applied", I would like to set `readonly` attribute to field `datepicker` and not allow it to be popup calendar.

My sample below produce two fields: Application Selection and DatePicker Fields:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#NextFollowDate').datepicker({
        format:"yyyy-mm-dd"
    });
    $('#ActivityType').on('change',function()
    {
        var actType = $(this).val();
        if (actType=='3')
        {
            $('#NextFollowDate').attr('readonly','readonly');
        }
        else
        {
            $('#NextFollowDate').removeAttr('readonly');
        }
    });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<select class="form-control" id="ActivityType" name="ActivityType">
    <option selected="" value="__None">--None--</option>
    <option value="1">1 - First Appoinment</option>
    <option value="2">2 - Second Appoinment</option>
    <option value="3">3 - Applied</option>
</select>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="NextFollowDate" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><label for="NextFollowDate">Next Date</label></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="NextFollowDate" name="NextFollowDate" type="text" value="" style="width: 214px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

From `readonly` attribute does not stop `DatePicker` field from popup at all. Yet, setting `$('#NextFollowDate').attr('disabled','disabled');`, it would working fine. However, it is problematic when I submitted the form; therefore, I would like it to be `readonly` and prevent calendar from pop up.

Is there any way that I can archived that with `readonly` attribute? Thanks.